# Google Scripts to Telegram - if statement issues when comparing strings

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

```
function sendText(id,text) {
  if(text == "hiii"){
    var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + "sup?";
  } else{ 
    var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + "yo yo yo";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

My issue is that in Google Scripts (back end to Google Sheets), I have this function that reads in a message from telegram and, if the message reads "hiii" it should respond "sup?". Currently my code does not do this and instead executes only the else statement.

Comment: Use the logger to test your variable text in the first place. Check if value and type are really what you expect.

Comment: For example, how about a modification from ``if(text == "hiii"){`` to ``if (text.indexOf("hiii") > -1) {``? In this case, if ``hiii`` is included in ``text``, it becomes ``true``.